# Why do we use squeeze(1) at this model definition with PyTorch?

Tags: classification, nlp, pytorch

PyTorch noobie here. I'm following an online tutorial and there's a simple model definition as follows:

```
class BagOfWordsClassifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, hidden1, hidden2):
        super(BagOfWordsClassifier, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(vocab_size, hidden1)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden1, hidden2)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(hidden2, 1)
        
    def forward(self, inputs):
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(inputs.squeeze(1).float()))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        return self.fc3(x)
```

What I don't understand here is **why do we need *inputs.squeeze(1)*** at the *forawrd* function? When I take it out it gives me the following error:

*"addmm_cuda" not implemented for 'Long'*

If you need additional info don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: squeeze(1) removes the 1st dimension out of your input tensor (inputs). Can you provide the shape of your inputs tensor?